# Return through observable subscribe / resolved promise to outer function in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to return the value from `Promise then` to template function.
I'm trying to pass by making promise from subscribe and then on completing promise return the answer.

How to do that, if i return any string in `template` function, it works fine

```
template: function (e: any) {
                    (function (e) {
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            let val: KeyValue<any> = new KeyValue<any>();
                            val.Key = m.field;
                            val.Value = e;
                            self.config.outGoingEvents.filter(p => p.Key == m.field)[0].Value.next(val);
                            self.config.inComingEvents.filter(p => p.Key == m.field)[0].Value.take(1).subscribe(m => {
                                resolve(m.Value);
                            });
                        }).then((resol: any) => {
                            debugger;
                            console.log(resol);
                            return resol;

                        });
                    })(e);
                }
```

I have even tried a single promise and it didnt work either.

```
template: function (e: any) {
     let a = (function() {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                resolve("AAA");
                            })
                        }).bind(this);

                        a().then(pl => {
                            console.log(pl);
                            return pl;
                        });}
```

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toPromise

Comment: if you are using toPromise with observables it is generally an indication that you have something wrong. Why are you using promises in this case and not using the observable directly?

Comment: i am actually trying to return from subscribe, i tried putting return statement in subscribe directly but it didnt work, how i can return to template function from subscribe